# How to access the main activity's view from a custom widget?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-custom-view, android-view

I have a custom "view" widget (CustomController) on my application's main screen.

In the widget's constructor, I can access an image in the widget's xml file with the following code:

(Note, img_cursor is an ImageView in "custom_controller.xml")

```
public final class CustomController extends LinearLayout{
    public CustomController(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view_controller = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_controller,this);

        img_cursor = (ImageView) view_dpad.findViewById(R.id.img_cursor);
...
```

However, I want to access a TextView on the main activity's screen.
The custom controller widget is displayed on the main screen through main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/linlayRoot"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
        <com.test.projectname.CustomController
        android:id="@+id/dpad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="15px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15px" /> 
        <Button 
        android:text="Connect" 
        android:id="@+id/btn_connection"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="100dp">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Settings" 
        android:id="@+id/btn_settings" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Debug x,y" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn_debug_x_y" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_view_x" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="X = 0">
        </TextView>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt_view_y"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Y = 0">
        </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

How do I access the TextViews in main.xml from the CustomController class?

I've tried stuff like:

```
public final class CustomController extends LinearLayout{
    public CustomController(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View main_controller = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main,this);

        textview = (TextView) view_dpad.findViewById(R.id.txt_view_x);
...
```

I can't seem to access the main screen's view. It doesn't like:

```
View main_controller = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main,this);
```

Thanks for any help!